# how to compress Input stream using c#?

Tags: c#, image

I have write code for the image upload using c# web api. now i want to image upload done with on server. and this thing is also done.but i want to compress the image then after upload on server. but how can do i have no idea any one know how can do that then please let me know. i want to compress image then upload on amzon s3 server using webapi.

This is my code =>

```
 [HttpPost]
[Route("FileUpload")]
public HttpResponseMessage FileUpload()
{
    try
    {               
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
            {
                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                string fname = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(postedFile.FileName.ToString());
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
                Image img = null;
                string newFileName = "";
                string path = "";
               img = Image.FromStream(postedFile.InputStream);
                string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageUploadPath"].ToString();
                newFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmssfff") + ".jpeg";
                string filePath = Path.Combine(path, newFileName);

                UploadImageOnServer(postedFile.InputStream,path + newFileName);
               } 
        }            
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }            
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Done");
}
```

This is my server on upload code =>

```
 public static void UploadImageOnServer(Stream File, string Key)
 {
  var client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

    PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = Bucketname,
        InputStream = File,
        CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
        Key = Key
    };
    PutObjectResponse response = client.PutObject(putRequest);
 }
```

This is my code now i want to compress image. please any one know then please let me know.

Comment: Compress in what sense? If it's uploaded as JPEG/PNG etc it'll already be compressed.

Comment: @Lloyd for ex. suppose i have upload some 10 mb size image then i want to compress size of the image.

Comment: Again if it's a JPEG or PNG it will already *be* compressed. The only way you're going to improve on that is through other options, like reducing it's size, the number of colours and for JPEG in particular the loss level but this is more image processing.

Comment: @Lloyd In c# you know like this code is available for the save image like this code EncoderParameters encoder_params = new EncoderParameters(1);

                encoder_params.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, compression);

                ImageCodecInfo image_codec_info =
                    GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg"); i want to this thing in my code  but how can do idk. on server just put stream value so

Comment: @Edit You're missing Lloyd's point - with an image, **it's already compressed**, so you compressing it in the program won't achieve anything; it's already as compressed as it's likely to get. It's like trying to write something that compresses a `.zip` file - you won't achieve anything, as it's already been done.

Comment: @Edit I worked for one hour on your latest question.  Then almost as soon as I had posted the answer, you deleted the post.  No thanks, no nothing.  Why?